# Отправить данные из формы в консоль

Tags: c#, winapi, консоль, ipc

Требуется из формы запустить окно консоли и отправлять туда данные, которые будут выводиться в консоли.

Консоль можно запустить так:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole ();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool FreeConsole ();
...
        /* где-нибудь в кнопке, а лучше в отдельном потоке
         * т.к. во время чтения из консоли основной поток
         * приложения будет заморожен */
        if (AllocConsole()) {
            Console.WriteLine("Ввод данных");
            Console.ReadLine();
            FreeConsole();
        }
```

Уже сталкивался с проблемами при отправке сообщений из окна в консоль. Подскажите гарантированно подходящий метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// ...

[DllImport("kernel32.dll",
         EntryPoint = "GetStdHandle",
         SetLastError = true,
         CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
         CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",
    EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",
    SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int AllocConsole();

private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
private const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

private void ShowConsole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
    IntPtr stdOutHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    var safeOutHandle = new SafeFileHandle(stdOutHandle, true);

    var outStream = new FileStream(safeOutHandle, FileAccess.Write);
    var standardOutput = new StreamWriter(outStream);
    standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(standardOutput);

    IntPtr stdInHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    var safeInHandle = new SafeFileHandle(stdInHandle, true);
    var inStream = new FileStream(safeInHandle, FileAccess.Read);
    var standardInput = new StreamReader(inStream);
    Console.SetIn(standardInput);

    Console.WriteLine("Type a message:");
    var msg = Console.ReadLine();
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Если будут проблемы с русскими буквами - спустите нужный Encoding вторым параметром в конструктор `StreamWriter`/`StreamReader`.

Но вообще гораздо проще зайти в свойства проекта и поменять там Output Type с Windows Application на Console Application. Единственная разница между этими типами - для Console Application консоль создается при старте приложения и всегда видна.

Comment: Великолепно! Я даже не подозревал, что всё может быть настолько просто. Теперь могу прямо из формы отправлять значения в консоль через `Console.WriteLine`.